# Can we deregister an exit handler that has been registered with atexit()

Tags: c, atexit

is it possible to unregister an exit handler function???

```
void exit_handler_1()
{
    printf("in first exit handler\n");
}

int main()
{
    if(atexit(exit_handler_1())
    {
        perror("error");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: @mata - It is tagged C not Python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible.

Why not just register one `atexit` function and have a global variable for that function to be able to decide what is required of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't unregister `atexit` functions, but you can disable your own functions.

```
static int disable_my_exit_handler = 0;

void exit_handler_1()
{
    if ( disable_my_exit_handler )
        return;

    printf("in first exit handler\n");
}

int main( void )
{
    if ( atexit( exit_handler_1 ) )
    {
        perror("error");
    }

    disable_my_exit_handler = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`atexit` allows a function to be registered multiple times too. In order to unregister a function, the non-existing `unregister_atexit` has to allow not only the function but also the position from which you want to unregister it. This quickly leads to exposing the interface of the stack used to keep store the functions registered by `atexit`.